# there are 2 QCheckBox chk1 and chk2, if we checked one of them like chk1 then other checkbox chk2 will automatically checked

Tags: qt

I have Two QCheckBoxes Qchk1 and Qchk2. if we checked one of them like Qchk1 then other checkbox Qchk2 will  automatically checked. In Qt.

Please Any one give idea.

Answer (score 1):

Connect Qchk1 `stateChanged(int state)` Signal to a function that changes the Checked State of Qchk2 by using it's `setChecked(bool val)` function and vice versa. Create two functions `on_Qchk1_stateChanged(int state)` and `on_Qchk2_stateChanged(int state)` like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_Qchk1_stateChanged(int state)
{
    if (state == 1) { ui->Qchk2->setChecked(true); }
    else if (state == 0) { ui->Qchk2->setChecked(false); }
}

void MainWindow::on_Qchk2_stateChanged(int state)
{
    if (state == 1) { ui->Qchk1->setChecked(true); }
    else if (state == 0) { ui->Qchk1->setChecked(false); }
}
```

If the name of your two QCheckBox widgets is Qchk1 and Qchk2 then Qt will automatically connect the Singal from those to the respective function, otherwise, you can connect it manually in the constructor of QMainWindow.

Comment: Or just `ui->Qchk<x>->setChecked(state)`